# Time Trackbar or Very Large Values using Trackbar

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, trackbar, gmap.net

I am writing a vehicle tracking application using GMAP.NET

I want to display simultaneous movement of multiple vehicle markers based on date/time.

For this, I would like to use a Trackbar such that when the User slides the trackbar, the corresponding movement of multiple markers is shown.

*I did the same application on the browser and it worked very well. I converted the datetime attribute of the marker tag to a UNIX Timestamp and then set the trackbar (NOUI Slider) values to the the UNIX Timestamp range.*

But, Now I find that I cannot do this at all with the Windows Desktop C# Trackbar.

The problems are:

1. The trackbar is unable to take very large timestamp values. Eg. 5 years data.
2. Even after reducing the very large numbers, the trackbar still cannot take such high values and keeps lagging or crashing.

> Eg. I need to show data for 5 years. In this case, my trackbar would have minimum value - 1262304000 (i.e. 01-01-2010) to 1425203100 (i.e. 01-03-2015 | 09:45).
>
> But such large values just don't work with my trackbar.
>
> I have even taken reduction eg. setting  1262304000 as 1 and then 162899100 (i.e. 1425203100 - 1262304000) becomes my maximum value.
>
> But even this is very intensive and the trackbar does not work.

**Please suggest if there is a time-trackbar which can show very a large datetimerange or how I can use a regular trackbar with very large values.**

The code as follows -

A. The function to convert datetime to a UNIX Timestamp

```
    public Int32 UnixTimeStampUTC(DateTime datetime)
    {
        Int32 unixTimeStamp;

        DateTime zuluTime = datetime.ToUniversalTime();
        DateTime unixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToUniversalTime();
        unixTimeStamp = (Int32)(zuluTime.Subtract(unixEpoch)).TotalSeconds;
        return unixTimeStamp;
    }
```

B. Taking the DateTime from a DataTable by Concatenating Date & Time Columns and Adding a third Column to hold the Unix TimeStamp of the DateTime Column

```
            for (int z = 0; z < dt.Rows.Count; z++)
            {

                if (reviseddt.Rows[z]["date"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    dte = DateTime.Parse(reviseddt.Rows[z]["date"].ToString());

                    dteticks = UnixTimeStampUTC(dte);

                }
                else
                {
                    dteticks = 0;
                }

                if (reviseddt.Rows[z]["time"].ToString() != "")
                {
                    tm = DateTime.Parse(reviseddt.Rows[z]["time"].ToString());

                    tmticks = UnixTimeStampUTC(tm);
                }
                else
                {
                    tmticks = 0;
                }


                Int32 fullDt = dteticks + tmticks;

                reviseddt.Rows[z]["datetime"] = fullDt.ToString();
                reviseddt.Rows[z]["datetimestring"] = reviseddt.Rows[z]["date"].ToString() + reviseddt.Rows[z]["time"].ToString();
```

C. Initalising the Trackbar by Getting the min and max values from the datetime column in the datatable and then taking the range as the difference between the min and max values. Hence, Trackbar range = 1 to (Max-Min)

```
string strminlevel = toplotDataTable.Compute("min(datetime)", String.Empty).ToString();
string strmaxLevel = toplotDataTable.Compute("max(datetime)", String.Empty).ToString();

Int32 minLevel = Convert.ToInt32(strminlevel);
Int32 maxLevel = Convert.ToInt32(strmaxLevel);

Int32 rangeint = maxLevel - minLevel;

trackBarMoveTarget.Maximum = rangeint;
trackBarMoveTarget.Minimum = 1;
trackBarMoveTarget.LargeChange = 100;
trackBarMoveTarget.SmallChange = 1;
```

Comment: Please show us your code! You should read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I don't think the code will make any difference here. 

What does my code do ?

1. Converts datetime to Unix Timestamp (common function I took off the net)
2. Sets the range for the Trackbar 

--> My basic question is how can the trackbar work with very large values? Or is there any other method?

Comment: You should always post your code. That's the correct etiquette here. Nonetheless, I'll give you a hint - `LargeChange`, `SmallChange`, `TickFrequency`.

Comment: Also, since you don't know how to solve this you shouldn't jump to the conclusion that the code won't help. In fact when we answer questions we love having a [mcve] so that we can see your problem in action and we can then verify that our answer is correct before we post.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Engimativity. :) Please refer to the comments below by Ubercoder and do let me know if you can help out in that manner. :) Really stuck here!

Comment: Ubercoder is wrong with his answer. Have you looked at the hint I gave you - `LargeChange`, `SmallChange`, `TickFrequency`? I got my test code working with a value range from `-214,748,363` to `214,748,363` without any loss of performance. But I need to see your code to know how to apply it to your situation.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity, was out the whole day. Just added the code. Please take a look. :)

Comment: Just added the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with using `TrackBar` at this kind of scale.

First you need to be able to move the track bar left and right, but if the `SmallChange` and `LargeChange` properties are too small then you may be making a lot of progress, but it simply doesn't show on the track bar. Try this for a start:

```
trackBarMoveTarget.Maximum = rangeint;
trackBarMoveTarget.Minimum = 1;
trackBarMoveTarget.LargeChange = rangeint / 50;
trackBarMoveTarget.SmallChange = rangeint / 200;
```

The other problem is that the `TrackBar` control tries to render helpful little tick marks along its length. By default the `TickFrequency` is `1` and the `Maximum` value is `10`. When You set `Maximum` to `162899100` without changing `TickFrequency` then the poor `TrackBar` control has to try and render `162899100` tick marks and that takes a long time. Try this:

```
trackBarMoveTarget.TickFrequency = rangeint / 100;
```

Comment: HI! Thank you for the hint. I am doing a work-around using both your answers. :) As there are limitations with trackbar and I understand now. There's a lot of heavy UI work in my application as multiple markers are redrawn along the map basing on the trackbar movement.  I will work to reduce this. Also, unable to score the answer as I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Be realistic - the trackbar only has a resolution down to 1 pixel - most displays are, at the most 1920 pixels wide. Therefore the resolution only has to be 1920 - let's round it up to 2000.

Now you have a 5 year period = 5 * 365 + 1 (for the odd leap year) = 1826. This is almost equal to our original 2000 odd. So let's make it 1826.

So set the Minimum value to 0 and the Maximum to 1826.

When you get the track event you take the first date 01-01-2010 and add the value of the trackbar to it:

```
var firstDate = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1).Date;

var trackDate = firstDate + TimeSpan.FromDays(trackBar.Value);
```

easy and quick.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This will work perfectly if the value are only days. But in my case, it is right down to the minute. A typical value is "01-01-2013 09:35". Please advise.

Comment: As I started at the outset, the track bar cannot possibly have a resolution of minutes, or even hours, over a 5 year period. It's limited by the UI which has screen resolution limitations. It has a finite number of positions that you can slide the track bar to. That number is of the order of about 1900. So you can only divide your five year period into about that many slices which is just over one day.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and I really appreciate your taking time out to help. But how do the JQuery Sliders work? I used NoUISlider (http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) and it worked perfectly when the application was browser-based with the same 5 years datetime range.

Comment: Ubercoder: Hi! Sorry I am unable to score your answer as I don't have reputation. (I don't know how it says -1) Thank you. I have realised there is a limitation with the trackbar and have to work around it using yours and @Enigmativity's solution.